# button click function will not work after insert button

Tags: jquery

this is my situation:

```
<button id="btnSendInvoice">Button A</button>

// Btn Send Invoice
$('#btnSendInvoice').click(function() {
  console.log(BUTTON A)

  $("#btnSendInvoice").text("Button B")
  $("#btnSendInvoice").attr("id","btnSetPayment")

});

// Btn Set Payment
$('#btnSetPayment').click(function() {
    console.log(BUTTON B)
});
```

Optical it works. If I pressed Button A, I get in console "Button A" and the button text changed to Button B, also the ID to btnSetPayment.

If I press now the "new" Button B, I get Button A in console again.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason you code did not work is because what happen is while code execute `$('#btnSendInvoice').click(function() {` line it will find element with `id` as `btnSendInvoice` and assign event & its `function` to that element. At the beginning you have button`with`id btnSendInvoice` so it will assign that function to it.
2. On next line it executes `$('#btnSetPayment').click(function() {`, so it will find element with `id` as `btnSetPayment` but at that moment there won't be any such element so this event will not be assigned to any element.
3. Later when you click on `Button A` you change its `id` but event is bind with `element` itself so event won't be changed and it will continue triggering same old function.

**Solution 1**

1. Update your existing `$('#btnSendInvoice').click(function() {` function and add conditional code using conditions like `if ($(this).attr("id") == "btnSendInvoice") {` & `if ($(this).attr("id") == "btnSetPayment") {`. Complete code is as below.

```js
// Btn Send Invoice
$('#btnSendInvoice').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "btnSendInvoice") {
    console.log("BUTTON A")
    $("#btnSendInvoice").text("Button B")
    $("#btnSendInvoice").attr("id", "btnSetPayment")
  } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "btnSetPayment") {
    console.log("BUTTON B")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSendInvoice">Button A</button>
```

**Solution 2**

1. You can use `delegate` binding using `$(document).on("click", "#btnSendInvoice"`. Using this it will bind event to `document` and on click it will try to find `delegate event` using `id` of current element or any other valid `selectors`. So it will work. Try like below.

**P.S.** `Delegate` events may impact on performance.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnSendInvoice", function() {
  console.log("BUTTON A")
  $("#btnSendInvoice").text("Button B")
  $("#btnSendInvoice").attr("id", "btnSetPayment")
});

// Btn Set Payment
$(document).on("click", "#btnSetPayment", function() {
  console.log("BUTTON B")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSendInvoice">Button A</button>
```